# add conditionally an Angular Bootstrap popover inside an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using AngularJS with Angular UI Bootstrap.

In my template i need to show a table, i create it with an ng-repeat, I need to add a popover on click only for certain cells.

I made something like this example:
[popover example inside ng-repeat in plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/bwzSnUfWXBMlreKwYdWX/preview)

How is the better way to have the popover conditionally only in certain cells?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the working demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NJkfod1hqhrUoSskBWrZ?p=preview). Only the cell with `value > 5.0` will show popover (in green background color).

Define a function on the `$scope`:

```
$scope.filterCells = function (v) {
    return v > 5.0 ? 'mouseenter' : 'none';
};
```

And the `td` HTML:

```
<td data-ng-repeat="v in getRowData(row)" class="zscore" 
    ng-class="{'show-popup': filterCells(v)}" popover="{{zscores[row][$index]}}" 
    popover-trigger="{{ filterCells(v) }}" 
    popover-append-to-body="true" popover-title="zScore">
    {{ v | number:1 }}
</td>
```

Comment: Is a very good solution, but there is a strange behaviour.
The cells with value > 5.0 will show popover on mouseenter, but other cell show popover on click too.
I could avoid popover open on click on the non admitted cells?

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 8.2.0 + ng-bootstrap and the Ngb Popover directive**

I came across this question while trying to fix my issue, so I'm including my solution here.

I had an issue using the `triggers` property to conditionally show/hide popovers. It turns out that the `triggers` value is consumed by the popover in `ngOnInit`, so it does not show/hide the popover after the component is already initialized.

I found that `ngbPopover` has a property called `disablePopover` that accomplishes what I need instead of using `triggers`.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api

**Before**

HTML

```html
<div
  ngbPopover="Hello, World!"
  [triggers]="triggers">
</div>
```

TypeScript

```js
private readonly TRIGGERS_ENABLED = 'mouseenter:mouseleave';
private readonly TRIGGERS_DISABLED = 'none';
public triggers = TRIGGERS_DISABLED;

someEvent() {
  if (someConditional) {
    this.triggers = TRIGGERS_DISABLED;
  } else {
    this.triggers = TRIGGERS_ENABLED;
  }
}
```

**After**

HTML

```html
<div
  ngbPopover="Hello, World!"
  triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
  [disablePopover]="disablePopover">
</div>
```

TypeScript

```js
public disablePopover = true;

someEvent() {
  if (someConditional) {
    this.disablePopover = false;
  } else {
    this.disablePopover = true;
  }
}
```